# Issues with multiple instances of same Fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

**Context:** SubFragment1

**Desired result:**
In onRefresh I want x to == z, in the example z is 1.

**Problematic Result:**

[image: My Result]

**Solution**
Removing the multiple instances of SubFragment1
**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new SubFragment1(...);
            case 1:
                return new SubFragment1(...);
            case 2:
                return new SubFragment1(...);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

**Question:**
Any idea how using multiple instances of one fragment within a viewPager, would break break the fragment's logic or standard lifecycle behaviour? Nothing was static, variables were private.

Comment: There are no inherent issues in using multiple instances of the same `Fragment` class in a `ViewPager`. If you're having problems, you'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, along with a detailed description. The diagram is not enough to let us know what's wrong, specifically.

Comment: I'm just wondering if anybody had a similar experience, or knew of any weird behaviours of the fragment lifecycle in this context.

Comment: "Weird" is quite subjective. If you don't know how a `ViewPager` and `Fragment`s work, then several different things might seem weird. As it is, it's hard to tell what you're even describing, despite the very nifty diagram.

Comment: good point. I've read the theory in android docs, but more can be learned from the experience of other people.

Comment: May i know is x static variable in SubFragment1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, buddy, I was in such mess once.

So what I did was, I used Five instances of same `SubFragment` and boy I was in trouble. Basically I had Five different screens with similar functionality(responsibility) but almost the same layout(UI design). 
As a result, I decided to use the same `SubFragment` just to promote the principle of **Code Reusability**.

Initially, the requirements were small and everything was smooth, but later as changes(requirements) kept on piling I had nightmares managing them.

**Let me give you an example:**

So let's say there is a method `checkLocationAndNotify()` which will check if a location is available and will show a `Dialog` if no location was found.

Now I wanted this method to be called only when my third instance of `SubFragment` would open on `ViewPager`(User Swipes and reach third Child on `ViewPager`).

So I placed this method call in the `onViewCreated()` lifecycle method of `SubFragment`. Boom this was the first of my troubles. As soon as the user opened any of the `ViewPager` child, irrespective of the instance of `SubFragment` this method was called and kept showing `LocationDialog` every time.

To resolve this, I had to put a check with respect to `childPosition` inside `ViewPager`.
Also, I had to repeat this wherever I wanted some logic to work only on a certain instance of `SubFragment`.

**Golden Advice:**

If dealing with `Fragments`(even with slightly different responsibility) that too inside `ViewPager` **please use different `Fragments`** and **promote the Single Responsibility principle over Code Reusability**.

Comment: @Dylan that's what SO is for. You don't commit same mistake twice.